# Scio Apache Beam - How to properly separate a pipeline code?

Tags: scala, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I have a pipeline with a set of PTransforms and my method is getting very long.

I'd like to write my DoFns and my composite transforms in a separate package and use them back in my main method. With python it's pretty straightforward, how can I achieve that with Scio? I don't see any example of doing that. :(

```
     withFixedWindows(
        FIXED_WINDOW_DURATION,
        options = WindowOptions(
          trigger = groupedWithinTrigger,
          timestampCombiner = TimestampCombiner.END_OF_WINDOW,
          accumulationMode = AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING_FIRED_PANES,
          allowedLateness = Duration.ZERO
        )
      )
      .sumByKey
      // How to write this in an another file and use it here?
      .transform("Format Output") {
        _
          .withWindow[IntervalWindow]
          .withTimestamp
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to bundle your `map, groupBy, ...` transformations in a separate package, and use them in your main pipeline.

One way would be to use `applyTransform`, but then you would end up using PTransforms, which are not scala-friendly.

You can simply write a function that receives an SCollection and returns the transformed one, like:

```
def myTransform(input: SCollection[InputType]): Scollection[OutputType] = ???
```

But if you intend to write your own Source/Sink, take a look at the [ScioIO class](https://spotify.github.io/scio/internals/ScioIO.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function to map your elements [example](https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/ca8d49c16adf30ce41e9d27e6729d4ee9422e360/scio-examples/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/examples/extra/TypedBigQueryTornadoes.scala#L52).

Instead of passing a lambda, you can pass a method reference from another class
Example `.map(MyClass.MyFunction)`

Comment: this should works for a DoFn but how can I separate my composite transforms and keep the context?

Comment: I don't have a very good idea but I think you can use use `.applyTransform(MyTransform)` to pass in the composite transform and get the context as its done here https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/6d79f32660954dde5a8d6984698b690deae6723f/scio-bigtable/src/it/scala/com/spotify/scio/bigtable/BigtableBenchmark.scala#L74

Answer (score 1):

I think one way to solve this could be to define an object in another package and then create a method in that object that would have the logic required for your transformation. For example:

```
def main(cmdlineArgs: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val (sc, args) = ContextAndArgs(cmdlineArgs)

    val defaulTopic = "tweets"
    val input = args.getOrElse("inputTopic", defaulTopic)
    val output = args("outputTopic")

    val inputStream: SCollection[Tweet] = sc.withName("read from pub sub").pubsubTopic(input)
      .withName("map to tweet class").map(x => {parse(x).extract[Tweet]})

    inputStream
      .flatMap(sentiment.predict) // object sentiment with method predict

  }
```

```
object sentiment  {

  def predict(tweet: Tweet): Option[List[TweetSentiment]] = {
    val data = tweet.text
    val emptyCase = Some("")
    Some(data) match {
      case `emptyCase` => None
      case Some(v) => Some(entitySentimentFile(data)) // I used another method, //not defined
    }

  }
```

Please also this link for an example given in the [Scio examples](https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/c466ae17a484b2d7156a3b5851cfa715e806594c/scio-examples/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/examples/extra/RefreshingSideInputExample.scala#L87)